# Having trouble identifying popu-up window close button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, groovy

I'm having major trouble identifying the close button on this pop-up window.

I've tried a css selector looking for "popup-close" and "icon-close" and neither work. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Need help on this one.

```
 @FindBy(css = "div[class='popup-close']")
 private WebElement closeEmailConfirmationWindow

 <section class="ng-scope" role="logInPopup">
   <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="popup-close close">
       <a ng-click="$close()">
         <i class="icon-close"></i>
       </a>
     </div>
   <div class="row small">
     <h3 su-translate="user.resetPasswordConfirmTitle.label">You're nearly there…</h3>
     <p su-translate="user.resetPasswordConfirm.label">Check your email and click on the link within to reset your password. The link will expire, so get moving!</p>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: This can be closed, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues here:

1. The class used in the selector is not an exact match to the HTML. The div element in the HTML snippet is: `<div class="popup-close close">`

There are a few ways to address this (listed only 2 options here):

a. Use a partial starts with match `div[class^='popup-close']`

b. Use the entire class in the selector: `div[class='popup-close close']`

2. Ideally, you need to click on the 'a' not the div. In this case, the 'a' tag can be identified by completing one of the css selectors above to include the child element

`div[class^='popup-close']>a`

OR

`div[class='popup-close close']>a`